# Split dataframe column containing list inside a string to two columns

Tags: python, string, pandas, split

I have a df where one column, 'vals' contains a list inside a string. I want to convert this into two columns 'val1'
 and 'vals2. I have tried to split and strip the string but can't find an implementation to do this for every row in the df.

```
    vals
'[12.1, 15.0]'

val1  val2
12.1  15.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) with [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and casting to floats if necessary, last add prefix by [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'vals':["'[12.1, 15.0]'","'[12.1, 15.0]'"]})

df = (df['vals'].str.strip("'[]")
               .str.split(', ', expand=True)
               .astype(float)
               .add_prefix('val'))
```

If no missing values and performance is important:

```
df =  pd.DataFrame([x.strip("'[]").split(', ') for x in df['vals']], 
                    columns = ['val1', 'val2']).astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we employ [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)-

```
import ast
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['[12.1, 15.0]','[12.4, 11.1]']})
df['val1']=df['A'].apply(lambda x:ast.literal_eval(x)[0])
df['val2']=df['A'].apply(lambda x:ast.literal_eval(x)[1])
df    
                A  val1  val2
  0  [12.1, 15.0]  12.1  15.0
  1  [12.4, 11.1]  12.4  11.1
```